# Can not load 50 more random posts in 10K tools when handling specific type of flags

Tags: bug, flags, 10k-tools

When we handle flags through 10K tools we get 50 random posts in the flags tab via https://stackoverflow.com/tools/flagged and at the bottom we have a link which loads 50 more random posts which redirects to the same page (in other words it just refreshes the page). That is fine.

Now if we select a specific type of flags. E.g. `67 X not an answer`. it will redirect us to https://stackoverflow.com/tools/flagged?flagtype=answernotananswer which also loads 50 random posts and at the bottom of page it says:

> Showing 50 random posts; get [50 more](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/flagged)

But you can see that *50 more* link redirects us to `https://stackoverflow.com/tools/flagged` which should be `https://stackoverflow.com/tools/flagged?flagtype=answernotananswer` IMO. Because I am on specific flag type page.

<sup>PS: I just earned that privilege few days ago. So not sure whether it's a bug or by design. In Meta we rarely get few flags so I don't have experience here.</sup>

Comment: May be you can understand from this image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/kIEsC.png. Couldn't get better title.

Comment: Bottom line, the filter is lost. Pretty sure it was already reported, let me see....

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - On last Saturday I searched [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/10k-tools+bug) but couldn't find.

Comment: Because it was asked as feature request... don't ask me why! I [searched for the word "random" in that tag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5B10k-tools%5D+random). :)